# Pass a Symfony form from one view to another in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'm trying to make a tabs nav with a central block that contains a Symfony form.

When I click into a link in a tab navs, I reload the block with form and data.

But the issue is how to pass formView object from the first twig to the AJAX twig response view?

My controller

```
 /**
 * @Route("/change-tab/{tabId}", name="change_tab")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function changeTab(Request $request, $tabId): Response
{
    $firstElement = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Element::class)->findOneBy([
        'cart'=>$tabId,
    ]);

    return $this->render('partials/_bloc-cart.html.twig',[
        'firstElement '=> $firstElement ,
        //'form' => $request->getContent()
    ]);
}
```

My twig view

```
<div class="row p-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 px-0" id="bloc-form">
            {{ include('partials/_form.html.twig') }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the ajax JS :

```
 $(document).on('click', '.linkToChange', function () {
        $('.linkToChange.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        let formPlan = $('#bloc-form').data('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data : formPlan,
            url: "/ajax/change-tab/" + $(this).data('cart'),
            success : function (datas) {
                $('#bloc-form').html(datas);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways to do it, if you use the Form Component, you can do something like this:

```php
public function changeTab(Request $request, $tabId): Response
{
    $firstElement = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Element::class)->findOneBy([
        'cart'=>$tabId,
    ]);

    $form = $this->createForm(ElementType::class, $firstElement);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // Save if form is submitted and valid

    return $this->render('partials/_bloc-cart.html.twig',[
        'firstElement '=> $firstElement ,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/change-tab", name="change_tab", method="{POST}")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function changeTab(Request $request)
{
    $tabId = $request->get('tab_id');
    $firstElement = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Element::class)->findOneBy([
        'cart'=>$tabId,
    ]);

    $html = $this->render('partials/_bloc-cart.html.twig',[
        'firstElement '=> $firstElement ,
        //'form' => $request->getContent()
    ]);

    return $this->json(['html' => $html]);
}
```

Jquery:

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data : formPlan,
            url: "{{ url('change-tab') }}",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
               'tab_id' : $(this).data('cart'),  
            }
            success : function (data) {
                $('#bloc-form').remove();
                $('#bloc-form').html(data.html);
            }
        });
```