# Modify twig variable through js without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I have an array of objects which are rendered through for loop in twig template. I want to apply a filter-like mechanism where after selecting a category from a filter, list of elements in twig would update without refreshing a page and contain elements only from chosen category.

Until now I managed to pass chosen category value through ajax to Symfony controller, parse it, encode to JS and send it as a response and fetch it via ajax.

Here's some code:

```php
//variable passed to twig
        return $this->render('@Ad/ad_list.html.twig', [
            'adList' => $adList,
        ]);
```

```js
//An ajax call
$.ajax({
   url : $form.attr('action'),
   type: "POST",
   data : filters,
   complete: function(html) {
        console.log(html['responseJSON'])
   }
});
```

```php
//creating a response
$response = JsonResponse::fromJsonString($jsonContent);
$response->prepare($request);
$response->send();
```

```html
{% for ad in adList|slice(0, 9) %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to update passed variable ($adList) to twig via JS, so it would render elements from response?

Comment: Are Twig templates being rendered server side or client side?

Comment: I am using Symfony, so it's rendered server side.

Comment: So you can't change it via client side Javascript.

Comment: Instead of returning JSON you could return pre-rendered HTML from your server and (re)place your existing specific DOM with that new HTML

Comment: That would mean calling Symfony render function with updated parameter, right?

Comment: Exactly. Either render the complete twig template or create a new one that only has your `{% for ...` loop in it (less data to transfer)

Comment: Thank you for, I'll do that and give feedback of the outcome.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66785382/pass-a-symfony-form-from-one-view-to-another-in-ajax). It's perfectly possible to generate a route which can be called by ajax and just return a partial instead of the full template

Comment: It works :) Should I post an asnwer describing how it was solved thanks to your hints and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to brombeer and DarkBee help I achieved my goal. I did it by:

1. Creating new template which holds list of elements,
2. Rendering this new template in main template and passing there updated value

main template:

```html
<section>
    {% include '@Ad/ad_list_container.html.twig' %}
</section>
```

ad_list_container template:

```html
<div id="ad-list">
   {% for ad in adList %}
       ...
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

ajax call:

```js
$.ajax({
    url : $form.attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data : filters,
    success: function(response) {
        $('#ad-list').html(response);
    }
});
```

php controller:

```php
return $this->render('@Ad/ad_list_container.html.twig', [
   'adList' => $adList
]);
```